# ¿Como puedo Limpiar un Select y Poner su valor por defecto en un formulario angularJs?

Tags: angularjs, select

```
<div class="input-field col s12" style="margin-top: 30px; margin-bottom:10px; ">
      <select ng-model="formData.estadoActi" name="form.estadoActi">
       <option value="" disabled selected >Selecciona la opcion</option>
      <option value="En proceso">En proceso</option>
  <option value="Terminada">Terminada</option>

      </select>
   <label >Seleccione el estado</label>
```

Quiero saber como puedo crear una función en angularjs para que cuando presione un botón,  el select tome su valor por defecto que seria **seleccione su estado**. Intente modificando poniendo su valor vació pero no funciono ya que sigue apareciendo el mismo valor  que había seleccionado y la idea es que me ponga el por defecto:

```
  $scope.reset = function() {
    $scope.form.estadoActi="";

  };
```

Comment: Que version de angularjs estas utilizando? [Me funciona perfecto asignado un valor vacio al modelo del select](http://jsbin.com/gopaxabapa/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Sera proque en el metodo reset tienes `$scope.form.estadoActi` y en tu modelo del select `$scope.formData.estadoActi`? No son los mismos modelos.

Comment: Hola, no es eso,ya que yo lo identifico  con el name

Comment: Oh pero tienes razon deberian cambiar el valor en el modelo ,Muchas gracias eso era jeje esque me puse hace atraves del name

Comment: Lo publico como respuesta pra que quede registrado.

Answer (score 1):

El nombre del modelo que tienes en la etiqueta `ng-model` no es igual a la que tienes en el script.

En el html tienes:

```
<select ng-model="formData.estadoActi" name="form.estadoActi">
```

Mientras que en el script:

```
 $scope.form.estadoActi=""
```

Los nombres tienen que ser iguales. Reemplaza

```
<select ng-model="formData.estadoActi" name="formData.estadoActi">
```

Por:

```
 <select ng-model="form.estadoActi" name="formData.estadoActi">
```

O viceversa, segun entiendas.